# Alternative way of using regex for Visual Studio 2003

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2003

I built a example program to check a value with regex. This example is running up on Visual Studio 2012.

But the Regex doesn't exist on Visual Studio 2003.

My Question is: How can I check a value with a Visual Studio 2003 without using the Regex and 3rd parties library?

**My Source-Code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::string code1 = "{1N851111-8M32-2234-B83K-123456789012}";
    std::regex control("^[{]{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{12}[A-Za-z0-9]$[}]");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(code1, match, control))
    {
        std::cout << "MAtch found";

    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Match not found";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::regex` appeared since C++11, so it's expected that they are missing in VC2003.

Comment: How can you _'control'_ a value with regexes??

Comment: Alternatively you could use a 3rd-party library, like [PCRE](http://www.airesoft.co.uk/pcre) to solve your task. Check [this blog post](https://hiddencodes.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/build-and-use-pcre-in-windows/) to see details.

Comment: @ForceBru Probably, he means 'check' - would be a typical error for a native German speaker (if he is), where 'kontrollieren' can mean both check and control...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes, I'm German Speaker. I update the case again. How can I check a value without using 3rd-party library?

Comment: @Skydreampower, write _your own_ regex engine :P Or just use some `if` statements: check whether there are sufficient chars in a string, whether they consist of valid letters, check if there are a `-` after each group etc

Comment: This might better be asked, "How can I check if a string is a valid UUID without regex?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you do not want to use third party libraries (why, by the way?), you will have to go all the way by foot... (Sounds easy, doesn't it?)

At very first, your regex does not seem to be what you are after. Have you tried it? This one, at least, matches your example string:

```cpp
std::regex control("^[{][A-Za-z0-9]{8}([-][A-Za-z0-9]{4}){3}[-][A-Za-z0-9]{12}[}]$");
```

Then let's have a look at the regex (I'm going to use mine...):

`^` – fine, right from the start, so we do not have to search somewhere in the middle of the string...
`[{]` – must be an opening brace
`[A-Za-z0-9]{8}` – followed by exactly eight alphanumeric characters
`([-][A-Za-z0-9]{4}){3}` – a minus sign followed by for alphanumerics – the whole stuff three times
`[-][A-Za-z0-9]{12}` – another minus followed by telve alphanumerics
`[}]$` – closing brace at the end

So:

```cpp
bool isValid(::std::string const& value)
{
    if(value.length() != 38)
        return false;
    char const* v = value.c_str();
    if(*v++ != '{')
        return false;
    for(char const* end = v + 8; v != end; ++v)
    {
        if(!isalnum(*v))
            return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if(*v++ != '-')
            return false;
        for(char const* end = v + 4; v != end; ++v)
        {
            if(!isalnum(*v))
                return false;
        }
    }
    if(*v++ != '-')
        return false;
    for(char const* end = v + 12; v != end; ++v)
    {
        if(!isalnum(*v))
            return false;
    }
    return *v == '}';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. I grown up with regex to checking a value. :)